# Create black and white image pixel value histogram C# EmguCv

Tags: c#, emgucv

This is the code that I am using

```
        int[] histogram = new int[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            histogram[i] = 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < img.Height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < img.Width; j++)
            {
                int n = (int)img.Data[i, j, 0];
                histogram[n] = histogram[n] + 1;
                //list.Add(n, hist[n]);
            }
        }

        float sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("i = " + i + " hist = " + histogram[i]);
        }
```

Could someone please help me as to why the values are being summed up at every 17 positions

```
i = 0 hist = 52
i = 1 hist = 0  
i = 2 hist = 0
i = 3 hist = 0
i = 4 hist = 0  
i = 5 hist = 0
i = 6 hist = 0 
i = 7 hist = 0
i = 8 hist = 0
i = 9 hist = 0
i = 10 hist = 0
i = 11 hist = 0
i = 12 hist = 0 
i = 13 hist = 0 
i = 14 hist = 0 
i = 15 hist = 0
i = 16 hist = 0
i = 17 hist = 1025
```

And so on .....
Can someone please help me

Comment: Maybe it's in the data? if only every 17th value is used the result could be just right.

Comment: instead of accessing the value of the intensity like this - img.Data[i, j, 0], why don't you try this img.Data[j, i, 0]. Also, is the img a Image<Gray,byte> type or Image<Bgr,byte>?